# Related questions vote column too narrow

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, related-questions

Did anyone else notice the vote column is too narrow for 4-digits (1000+ votes)?

Seems like a very minor issue, but I thought I'd just point it out.

If we don't want to widen it (and still have the title in a new line), we may want to consider aligning the text with the other questions.

[Sample question showing this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16595167/1711796).

[image: Related]

Comment: Get those k-s in.

Comment: We may also have to consider downvoting that question into submission.

Comment: option a: widen it by a couple of pixels. option b: downvote the question 119 times. :P

Comment: May have a bit more of a problem with the 3633 votes required to get [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/1711796) below 1000.

Comment: We might have to put a 999 score limit on all questions...

Comment: @Dukeling Challenge accepted...

Comment: I don't have any 1K+ questions, so we might as well downvote them back to 999... :P

Comment: [This has been fixed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0W6Dy.png) by now.

Answer (score 12):

I think we should take the same approach we do elsewhere and use rounding - 1k, 2k, etc.

Basically, use the same behaviour we already do on /questions and the home page for consistency.

Comment: Any idea [who fixed it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0W6Dy.png)? :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It's better, but it's not exactly the ideal fix as now all the titles no longer start at the same left position (which is not exactly good UI design).

Comment: @Dukeling still a fix - it's no longer "falling down".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd As a technicality, I pointed out that the column is too narrow, not that it's 'falling down'.