# Related question score text CSS

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, related-questions

I just observed related questions [on this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) contained a post that has a score higher than 999, causing it to look different from the others:

> [image: related]

I think it should be consistent.

As per [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181244/related-questions-vote-column-too-narrow?rq=1), either it should show `1k` or it should look something like:

> [image: original]

The post is marked as status-completed but it still appearing not fixed to me:

> [image: after change]

Comment: Can you please unaccept the answer? The bug returned after the MSE/MSO split. :(

Comment: Please open a new bug, we don't see status completed bugs in our list and this serves as a useful record of the past.

Comment: @Sklivvz its already posted http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233606/183757

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed and it will be out in the next build

Comment: Please see the post it still appearing same.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233606/small-overlapping-text-on-related-questions